# HTML5 Canvas Soft Brush

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paint, brush

What are the different methods of creating a `"soft brush"` effect when drawing on an HTML5 canvas? Speed and efficiency is important so if anyone has any benchmarks on the different methods, that would be awesome.

To elaborate on what I mean by a `"soft brush"`, I mean a brush that has essentially a radial alpha transparency on it so that the edges are more transparent than the center.

I've heard several methods, including painting to a memory canvas and applying a `blur`. However, I can't imagine that this approach is very efficient.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like an opportunity to experiment and come up with something new.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add a shadow below a line:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-shadow-offset-tutorial/

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.rect(188, 40, 200, 100);
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.shadowColor = '#999';
  context.shadowBlur = 20;
  context.shadowOffsetX = 15;
  context.shadowOffsetY = 15;
  context.fill();
</script>
```

by setting offsets to 0, the blurring will be done by the browser instead of your code.